# Sequencing project/solution build and cmd file executing in custom MSBuild file

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild, msbuild-task, msbuild-propertygroup, msbuild-target

I need to tie together a bunch of steps which include building solutions, projects and running .cmd files using a custom MSBuild file.

My first pass at this is below:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
   </PropertyGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\Hosts\solution1.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\..\solution2.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="helper1.csproj"></ProjectsToBuild>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\..\Sandboxes\helper2.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
      <Exec Include="" Command="CALL GetFiles.cmd"/>
      <ProjectsToBuild Include="wix\proc\prod.wixproj"></ProjectsToBuild>
      <Exec Command="CALL final.cmd"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   <Target Name="Build">
      <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Targets="Build">
        <Output ItemName="ProjectOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>
    <Message Text="@ProjectOutputs"/>
   </Target>       
</Project>
```

This resulted in an error since the Exec element is in the wrong place.

Basically, I need to build solution1.sln, solution2.sln,helper1.csproj and helper2.sln (in sequence), then, run the file GetFiles.cmd, then build prod.wixproj followed by running the final.cmd file.

I have looked at MSDN ([here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171473.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd637714.aspx), [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)), [a blog](http://sedodream.com/PermaLink,guid,ed3a0c98-fdac-4467-9116-5b3bf6755abc.aspx), and browsed through various stackoverflow questions (including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3278168/alter-itemgroup-content-sequence), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6036748/how-do-i-perform-the-exec-task-in-a-loop-with-msbuild-itemgroups/6036878#6036878), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013054/how-can-i-execute-programs-in-my-path-with-msbuild), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991904/msbuild-build-sequence)), but none of them quite address what I am trying to do. This is the first time I have ever worked with MSBuild, so it is possible I may have missed something. Will appreciate any pointers...

Comment: You can use targets to control the sequence in which you build the solutions.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee216359.aspx

Comment: @NickCarlson Thanks. But how do I link ItemGroup to Target?

Comment: ItemGroup can also be a child node of Target.  Each target could have it's own item group it is responsible for.  You could specify the build order at the <Project/> level, or through the various *Targets attributes on the <Target/> level. (below)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since an ItemGroup node can be a child of a Target node, break down those ItemGroup members into separate targets, then use the DefaultTargets attribute to control the sequence in which those are built.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Target1;Target2;Target3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" ToolsVersion="3.5" >
    <Target Name="Target1">
        <Message Text="Target 1" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Target2">
        <Message Text="Target 2" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Target3">
        <Message Text="Target 3" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The build projects are already in the correct order see:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\Hosts\solution1.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\..\solution2.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="helper1.csproj"></ProjectsToBuild>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="..\..\Sandboxes\helper2.sln"></ProjectsToBuild>
    <ProjectsToBuild Include="wix\proc\prod.wixproj"></ProjectsToBuild>

  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="Build">
    <Exec Command="CALL GetFiles.cmd"/>
    <Message Text="Build order: %(ProjectsToBuild.Identity)"/>

    <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectsToBuild)" Targets="Build">
      <Output ItemName="ProjectOutputs" TaskParameter="TargetOutputs"/>
    </MSBuild>
     <Message Text="@(ProjectOutputs)"/>

    <<Exec Command="CALL final.cmd"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

At the start the order of the itemgroup is displayed:

Project "C:\Test\Testcode\build\testcode.msbuild" on node 1 (default targets).

Build:

Build order: ..\Hosts\solution1.sln

Build order: ....\solution2.sln

Build order: helper1.csproj

Build order: ....\Sandboxes\helper2.sln

Build order: wix\proc\prod.wixproj

All done.

Comment: I need to run GetFiles.cmd between building helper2.sln and prod.wixproj. Please correct me if I am wrong, but it doesn't look like that will be the case in your answer.

Comment: If thats the case then you need to split the itemgroup and call the msbuild target using each itemgroup.